# How to find unknown parameters existed in several constraints?

Tags: matlab, math, constraints

Here exist several constraints include **2** unknown parameters **(K1,eta)**:

[image]

How can I get the **(K1 , eta)** Values using Matlab that fulfill all relations?

Comment: Why does this question have 5 upvotes (and 1 downvote) and 2 favourites?  This is a pure `gimme teh codez` question with no effort shown by the OP.  This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can graphically solve the problem.

You can refactor the equations into equations of lines and sweep a region over K1 (which will constrain eta). The inequalities you can keep as lines but be cognizant of which side of the line matches the inequality and do some shading in your final plot.